# Difference between console.log and logger.log in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I am currently working with nodejs application. We use `console.log` for server side printing purpose, But here `logger.log` also used. Both will do the same work, but `logger.log` isn't able to be used more than once in a function like below

```
logger.log('check level 1')
logger.log('check level 2')
```

anybody can help?

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)? If not it looks like you are using another library. Can you hunt it?

Comment: `logger.log` isn't part of node. You're using a library. Read the documentation for that library.

Comment: Even if he's using winston or log4js, I don't see how the logger wouldn't be able to log twice in the same function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got Answer,

**Console.log**

> - only shows the output in console, doesnot store on anywhere. It only used on runtime

**logger.log**

logger is the customized class in my project, which enables with utiles modules for debugging modules.

if i missed anything, please point out my mistakes

Comment: Its not a right answer. @SuperKrish logger.log is not a part of Node. May be its an object of some other class. So, Please mention, what the logger is.